# Settlement area from buildings layer

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, polygon-creation

I'm using QGIS 3.22.0 Bialowieza.
I have an osm-building-Layer. I would like to transform the single buildings into a settlement area as you can see in the image.[image: settlementarea]

In the image you can see the buildungs (yellow as a layer), in the background you can see a basemap. In the basemap the settlement area as a whole is shown (in grey). I thought by merging the building-layer I could get a settlement area, but obviously this didnt work. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You could use convex_hull or concave_hull on the building polygons to create a polygon that includes all the building polygons.  Or, you could try finding the layer in OSM - https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Boundaries

Comment: Here is the link to the osm urban area polygon, is that what you are looking for?https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/114521267#map=15/47.8584/8.3120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **QGIS** [3.26 used]

Zoom to Area of Interest
Load the **Quick OSM tool**

go to Query in the tool

use the code

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“landuse=residential ”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “landuse=residential”
  node["landuse"="residential"]({{bbox}});
  way["landuse"="residential"]({{bbox}});
  relation["landuse"="residential"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

The query will create a temporary virtual layer OSMQuery

Right Click to save to a format you need.

[image]